# Cómo resolver este problema usando ciclos while o for?

Tags: python, array, bucles, python-3.7

Estoy realizando una guia de ejercicios con Python , en aspcectos generales pide usar Diccionario de datos, y hacer los calculos de Descuento e Impuesto, sin embargo soy nuevo usando el lenguaje, a prueba y error he llegado hasta alli. ¿Pero como podria hacer ese procedimiento iterando, me refiero usando un WHILE O FOR?
muchas gracias por la colaboracion

```
Stock={'harina' : 1,
      'azucar' : 1,
      'sal'    : 1,
      'pan frances': 1,
      'jamon'  : 2,
      'queso'  : 3,
      'frijoles':1
     
      }
inventario = list(Stock)
print(Stock)

descuento =  list(Stock )
print (descuento)
#precios del Stock
precio = list(Stock.values())
precio_harina = list(Stock.values())[0]
precio_azucar = list(Stock.values())[1]
precio_sal = list(Stock.values())[2]
precio_pan = list(Stock.values())[3]
precio_jamon = list(Stock.values())[4]
precio_queso = list(Stock.values())[5]
precio_frijoles = list(Stock.values())[6]
#descuentos del Stock
harina_desc = list(Stock.values())[0] * 0.10
azucar_desc = list(Stock.values())[1] * 0.10
sal_desc = list(Stock.values())[2] * 0.10
pan_desc = list(Stock.values())[3] * 0.10
jamon_desc = list(Stock.values())[4] * 0.10
queso_desc = list(Stock.values())[5] * 0.10
frijoles_desc = list(Stock.values())[6] * 0.10
```

Comment: Sin mayúscula sostenida también te ponemos atención ;) Bienvenido!

Comment: lo lamento, es parte de la novatada... ahahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Te recomiendo leer sobre comprensión de listas y diccionarios, eso te va a facilitar mucho la vida en cuanto a iterables.

Ejemplo para imprimir los productos con sus precios y descuentos:

```
Stock = {'harina' : 1,
      'azucar' : 1,
      'sal'    : 1,
      'pan frances': 1,
      'jamon'  : 2,
      'queso'  : 3,
      'frijoles':1
     
      }

print(*[f'Precio {k}: {v} --> Descuento {k}: {v*0.1}' for k,v in Stock.items()], sep='\n')
```

Esto imprime:

```
Precio harina: 1 --> Descuento harina: 0.1
Precio azucar: 1 --> Descuento azucar: 0.1
Precio sal: 1 --> Descuento sal: 0.1
Precio pan frances: 1 --> Descuento pan frances: 0.1
Precio jamon: 2 --> Descuento jamon: 0.2
Precio queso: 3 --> Descuento queso: 0.30000000000000004
Precio frijoles: 1 --> Descuento frijoles: 0.1
```

**Nota adicional:** Como te podrás dar cuenta, el descuento de 3 salió como `0.30000000000000004`, esto se debe a la precisión de los números con punto decimal en `python`. Si desearas truncar a un número específico de decimales puedes leer [este](https://datagy.io/python-truncate-float/#:%7E:text=Conclusion-,Use%20the%20int%20Function%20to%20Truncate%20a%20Float%20in%20Python,by%20removing%20its%20decimal%20places.) artículo que muestra varios métodos para hacerlo.

Comment: `0.30000000000000004` -> Y por esto mismo se suele formatear los números al imprimirlos, especialmente cuando se trata de precios y cosas así donde no tiene sentido ver el 000000000004 extra

Comment: muchas gracias, se me habia ocurrido asi, pero no habia encontrado como hacerlo, me fui por list(Stock), pero se puede hacer con key y values segun entiendo tu ejemplo

Comment: Así es @RaymundoPeña, puedes obtener las llaves y los valores e iterar con ellos. Si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).